o y u (or and or)
In Spanish, the word 'or' is represented as 'o', with the exception of cases where the following letter starts with 'o' or 'ho' (including accented forms like 'ó' or 'hó'). Numbers also follow this rule if they start with \$8\$ or are exactly \$11\$, because all numbers that start with \$8\$ in Spanish starts with "och", like ocho (8), ochenta (80), ochocientos (800), etc, so these words start with 'o' and the number \$11\$ in Spanish is once, which starts with 'o'. The 'H' in Spanish isn't pronounced, so the "u" is used before the words that start with "Ho" with or without accent.
Examples:

Quiero unos 3 o 4 panqueques.


Quiero unos 7 u 8 panqueques.



¿Comió 34 panqueques, Octavio o Manuel?


¿Comió 78 panqueques, Manuel u Octavio?

Task
Your task is to choose "o" or "u" depending on the string (see below), that may contain alphanumeric characters, including these characters: ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúüÑñ (You may ignore these characters if your (programming) language doesn't support them, but instead use other characters of your choice (must be 13 characters long, including 2 characters that represent as "o", but these characters are obligatory if your language supports it)) in the shortest way, because this is code-golf. The characters of the strings can be uppercased even if they're not the first character of the string. Strings don't start with double "h" nor contain both numbers and letters. Also, if the string is a number, it's assumed to be less than 10999.
Output "o" if it meets one of the criteria below:

The string is a number, but it doesn't start with \$8\$, or isn't the number \$11\$

The string doesn't start with "o", "ó", "O" or "Ó"

The string doesn't start with "ho", "Ho", "hO", "HO", "hó", "Hó", "hÓ" or "HÓ" (sorry).


Output "u" if it doesn't meet a criterion above.
Testcases
alejandro => o
óleo => u
oreja => u
Hórrido => u
833 => u
8 => u
11 => u
1 => o
111 => o
6 => o
mal => o
horno => u
hOra => u
Héroe => o
Chocolate => o
WordInEnglish => o
OSO => u
Paro => o
o => u
u => o
O => u
U => o
Ho => u
Hu => o
Hueso => o
Humo => o
Húmedo => o


Did you mean to negate "The string is a number, and it starts with 8 or is exactly 11"?

@Aaron I negated, thank you for correcting me.

@LuisMendo 1) Yeah, I'm used to saying "panqueques" :-D 2) I added the explanation for that grammar rule, thank you. 3) That's my mistake, I added stress and added a testcase that starts with "o". Sorry.

Can I reduct this problem as [tag:decision-problem]?

the "u" is used after the words that start with "Ho" — did you mean before?

if anything this question goes to show how much locale support has improved over the years. 20 years ago, you could not have just matched case-insensitive on ó in most languages.

What about 11000 and 11000000, these would be "once mil" or "once millón", right?

@chtz I'm not going to handle this, because it's too big. only numbers less than 11000 are supported.

Should the solutions handle things like 11.2 (once punto dos)?

@terdon No, that's too complex, only simple inputs are supported. Read the challenge to know which to handle.

JavaScript (ES6), 35 bytes
-2 thanks to Fmbalbuena
s=>"ou"[+/^h?[oó8]|^11$/i.test(s)]

Try it online!

35 bytes since both letters and numbers in the same string isn't allowed.

R, 45 bytes
\(s)`if`(grepl("^h?[oó8]|^11$",s,T),"u","o")

Attempt This Online!
Port of @Arnauld's JavaScript regex answer.

Google Sheets, 49 bytes
=if(regexmatch(A1,"(?i)^h?[oó]|^11$|^8"),"u","o")

Put the string in cell A1 and the formula in B1. Expects that the data is text strings as specified in the question (Format > Number > Plain text). Uses Arnauld's regex.


Funny enough Excel can beat GS if it comes to regex since short. For example =IF(REGEXTEST(A1,"^h?[oó8]|^11$",1),"u","o")

QuadR i, 24 23 bytes
−1 thanks to Fmbalbuena.
^(11$|h?[oó8]).*
.+
u
o

Try it online!
If at the very beginning (^) we find any of the following:

"11" followed by the end ($)
an optional (?) "h" followed by "o" or "ó" or "8"

then we replace it and anything that follows it (.+) with a "u".
Everything else (.+) we replace with an "o".

-1 byte (It marks "h8" as true, but this is fine because in this challenge it says: "Strings don't [...] contain both numbers and letters.").

@Fmbalbuena Thanks!

Charcoal, 24 bytes
§uo∧⁻Ｎ¹¹⬤8oó⬤θ⌕↧θ⁺…hμι

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
     Ｎ                  Input as a number (zero if not)
    ⁻                   Subtract
      ¹¹                Literal integer `11`
   ∧                    Logical And
         8oó            Literal string `8oó`
        ⬤               All characters satisfy
             θ          Input string
            ⬤           All characters satisfy
                θ       Input string
               ↧        Lowercased
              ⌕         Does not start with
                     ι  Outer character
                 ⁺      Prefixed with
                   h    Literal string `h`
                  …     Extended to
                    μ   Inner index
§                       Index into
 uo                     Literal string `uo`
                        Implicitly print

Note that the version of Charcoal on TIO mistakenly counts ó as one byte but the version on ATO gets it right, or you can add the -x flag which produces an xxd style dump showing the correct number of bytes.

05AB1E, 24 bytes
„ouIl'hæ„óoâJ8ªÅ?àI11Q~è

Try it online or verify all test cases.
Explanation:
„ou             # Push "ou"
I               # Push the input-string
 l              # Lowercase it
  'h           '# Push "h"
    æ           # Pop and push its powerset: ["","h"]
     „óo        # Push "óo"
        â       # Cartesian product to create all possible pairs:
                #  [["","ó"],["","o"],["h","ó"],["h","o"]]
         J      # Join each together: ["ó","o","hó","ho"]
          8ª    # Append 8: ["ó","o","hó","ho","8"]
            Å?  # Check for each whether the lowercased input starts with it
              à # Check if any is truthy (by leaving the maximum)
I               # Push the input-string again
 11Q            # Check whether it equals 11
~               # Check if either of the two is truthy
 è              # Use that 0 or 1 to (0-based) index into the "ou"
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)


Nibbles, 41 nibbles (20.5 bytes)
? + ? `D256 o/-.$`)$"H"$ ==$"11" "u" "o" 384fd3

Attempt This Online!
   `D256 384fd3                   # decode from base-256
                                  # to [56,79,211]
  ?                               # now get the index in this of
        o                         #   codepoint of
         /         $              #   first element of
           .$`)$                  #   input mapped to uppercase
          -     "H"               #   without any "H"s
 +                                # add this to
                    ==$"11"       #   is the input equal to "11"?
?                                 # if the answer is non-zero
                           "u"    #    output "u"
                                  # otherwise
                              "o" #    output "o"


Retina 0.8.2, 26 24 bytes
Mi`^11$|^h?[8oó]
T`d`\ou

Try it online! Link includes test suite that removes the  => [ou] suffix to allow the test cases to be used as input. Explanation: Port of @Arnauld's JavaScript answer.
Mi`^11$|^h?[8oó]

Count the number of occurrences of the pattern in the input.
T`d`\ou

Index that into the string ou. (o is magic in transliteration mode so it needs to be quoted to be literal. d is also magic, being a byte shorter than writing 01.)
Edit: Saved 2 bytes by porting @Fmbalbuena's golf to @Arnauld's answer.

AWK -vIGNORECASE=1, 27 bytes
$0=/^11$|^h?[oó8]/?"u":"o"

Attempt This Online!

Java, 44 bytes
s->s.matches("(?i)11|(8|h?[oó]).*")?'u':'o'

Try it online.
Explanation:
s->     // Method with String parameter and character return-type
  s.matches("(?i)11|(8|h?[oó]).*")?
        //  If the String matches the full regex explained below:
    'u' //   Return 'u'
   :    //  Else:
    'o' //   Return 'o' instead

Regex explanation:
The String#matches method implicitly matches the entire String, adding a leading ^ and trailing $.
(?i)^11|(8|h?[oó]).*$
(?i)                    # Enable case-insensitive matching
    ^               $   # Match the entire string
     11                 #   It's "11"
       |                #  OR:
         8              #    It starts with an "8"
        ( |      )      #   or
           h?           #    An optional "h"
             [oó]       #    Followed by either "o" or "ó"
                  .*    #   Followed by 0 or more additional characters


Lexurgy, 60 bytes
r:
{{{h,H}? {o,ó,O,Ó}},\8} []*=>u/$ _
\11=>u/$ _ $
[]+=>o

Explanation
r:
{{{h,H}? {o,ó,O,Ó}},\8} []*=>u/$ _ # match /[hH]?[oóOÓ]|8/ at the start of the word, and replace it all with u
\11=>u/$ _ $                       # special case for 11
[]+=>o                             # everything else is o


Python, 64 62 60 bytes
Edit: -2 bytes thanks to @xnor and -2 bytes thanks to @squareroot12621.
lambda s:re.match("^h?[oó8]|^11$",s,2)and"u"or"o"
import re

Attempt This Online!
Port of @Arnauld's JavaScript regex answer.

Looks like you can pass the IGNORECASE flag as re.match(...,s,2).

@xnor thanks - I searched for something shorted than re.I, but couldn't find it.

-2 bytes: replace "^h?[oó]|^11$|^8" with "^h?[oó8]|^11$".

Python 3.8 (pre-release),  66  55 bytes
-11 bytes by realizing that strings like 'H8' are undefined behavior.
lambda s:'ou'[s.strip('hH')[:1]in[*'oóOÓ8']or'11'==s]

The list unpacking could be removed (-3 bytes) if strings matching /^[hH]*$/g could output 'u' instead of 'o'.
Try it online!

Go, 110 bytes
import."regexp"
func f(s string)string{o:="o"
if b,_:=MatchString(`(?i)^h?[oó]|^11$|^8`,s);b{o="u"}
return o}

Attempt This Online!
Uses the case-insensitive regexp that everyone else is using.

Bash, 47 bytes
-2 bytes by @Fmbalbuena with golfed regex
grep -qiE '^h?[oó8]|^11$'<<<$1&&echo u||echo o

Attempt This Online!
use as a body of a bash function or bash script, takes input as first argument and outputs to stdout.
explanation:
grep -qiE                  <<<$1 #match on the first argument, don't output matches, case-insensitive, extended expressions
          '^h?[oó8]|^11$'        #the expression we know and love at this point
                                &&echo u||echo o #if match, output u, o otherwise.


Are we allowed to use external commands? grep isn't [art of bash or linked to it in any way.

@terdon: bash used to be separated into 'pure bash' and 'bash+coreutils' but it is generally agreed that anything available on ATO or TIO is fair game, unless you specifically are going for pure bash.

Got it, thanks. +1 then!

Ruby, 41 33 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to Dingus

->s{s=~/^h?[oó]|^11$|^8/i??u:?o}

Attempt This Online!
Thanks to almost the same syntax, the regex is gratefully copypasted from the Arnauld's answer :D
(The following comment refers to the previous 41-byte version)
What I like here, is how three question marks appear together (alas, a space cannot be removed), each one having a different role: the first one is a part of the boolean expression that checks whether a value is nil, the second one belongs to the ternary operator and the last one is a shortcut for 'o'.

If you swap ?o and ?u then you can do away with .nil? and the parentheses, saving 7 bytes.

@Dingus ...and also the space isn't anymore necessary. Thanks!

even for platforms that don't support UTF-8 at all this challenge can still be safely coded up via octals
awk '$0=/^(11$|8[0-9]*|[Hh]?(O|o|\703[\223\663])[^0-9]*)/?"u":"o"'

but one can always hard-code in the UTF-8 bytes instead :
awk '$0=/^(11|8[0-9]*|[Hh]?(O|o|Ó|ó)[^0-9]*)$/?"u":"o"' 


Please, follow the rules on the CGCC; if you speak Chinese and customized awk languages you should be able to do it; it's not hard at all! We are sick of seeing your behaviors! 因为你们是中国人，所以你们认为没有警告就可以做任何事情，但我们和你们不同。 请大家效仿。
